# How to get points belonging to a specific side of a contour?

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm using OpenCV 2.9 c++, found a contour in an image with `findContours` and its bounding box:

[image]

The next step would be to get all contour points, which are stored in a `vector<Point>`, between S and E and likewise on the opposite edge (where the Contour arrow is pointing at). I've no clue how to extract those points, would be nice if you could help me out here.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

Points S and E are not priorly given, they are points of the contour intersecting the bounding box.

Comment: With cv::findContours you receive a list of points. Just use all the points between two chosen points of that list.

Comment: I guess in this example S could be the left lower bounding rect corner, but how do I obtain point E?

Comment: ah ok, thought you already have S and E extracted... You can find Corners in the (dense) contour point list by forward/backward/central differences. After detecting the corners, maybe you can say that the corner with the lowest distance to the bounding box corner correspond to it.

Comment: please mind, that S and/or E dont necessarily have to intersect the bounding box!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a method that works for synthetical data, but probably not for real contours. The problem there will be to find the corners, I just don't get the right way, although I thin I should know how to do it. The idea is to find some kind of "local extrema" which describe corners compared to their neighbors.

As I said, there must be something wrong, but I don't get it at the moment...

I generate this input:

[image]

use findContours and extract "extrema" (which only worked for my synthetical data):

[image]

after that, find correspondences between extrema and bounding box corners, and sort all contour points in between to bounding box segments:

[image]

maybe you can use some parts of that code and maybe the whole, if someone explains how to measure the corners/extrema in the contour correctly... the code isnt any optimized, many modulo operations etc... no encapsulation...

```
int main()
{
    cv::Mat input;
    input = cv::Mat::zeros(512,512,CV_8UC1);

    // generate something similar to the question:
    cv::Point2f topLeft  = 2*cv::Point2f(100,50);
    cv::Point2f topRight = 2*cv::Point2f(180,55);
    cv::Point2f bottomLeft  = 2*cv::Point2f(50,150);
    cv::Point2f bottomRight = 2*cv::Point2f(200,145);

    int lineWidth = 1;
    cv::line(input, topLeft, topRight, cv::Scalar(255),lineWidth);
    cv::line(input, topRight, bottomRight, cv::Scalar(255),lineWidth);
    cv::line(input, bottomRight, bottomLeft, cv::Scalar(255),lineWidth);
    cv::line(input, bottomLeft, topLeft, cv::Scalar(255),lineWidth);

    cv::Mat colored;
    cv::cvtColor(input,colored, CV_GRAY2BGR);


    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
    cv::findContours(input,contours,CV_RETR_EXTERNAL,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);


    if(contours.size() == 0) return 0;

    std::vector<cv::Point> relevantContour = contours[0];
    cv::Rect bb = cv::boundingRect(relevantContour);

    // display bb
    //cv::rectangle(colored, bb, cv::Scalar(0,0,255));


    // you can encapusalte that easily!

    // first "derivative" of conour
    std::vector<cv::Point2f> contourDifferences;
    std::vector<cv::Point> contourDifferencesPoints;
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<relevantContour.size(); ++i)
    {
        contourDifferences.push_back(relevantContour[i] - relevantContour[(i+2)%relevantContour.size()]);
        contourDifferencesPoints.push_back(relevantContour[(i+1)%relevantContour.size()]);
    }

    // second "derivative"
    std::vector<cv::Point2f> contourDifferences2;
    std::vector<cv::Point> contourDifferences2Points;
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<contourDifferences.size(); ++i)
    {
        contourDifferences2.push_back(contourDifferences[i] - contourDifferences[(i+2)%contourDifferences.size()]);
        contourDifferences2Points.push_back(contourDifferencesPoints[(i+1)%contourDifferencesPoints.size()]);
    }


    // local optima:
    std::vector<cv::Point> localOptima;
    float delta = 0.0f; // add some delta to overcome noise?!? not necessary for my example, but maybe good for real contours...
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<contourDifferences2.size(); ++i)
    {
        int cIdx = (i+1)%contourDifferences2.size();
        if(cv::norm(contourDifferences2[cIdx]) - delta > cv::norm(contourDifferences2[i]) 
            && cv::norm(contourDifferences2[cIdx]) - delta > cv::norm(contourDifferences2[(i+2)%contourDifferences2.size()]))
        {
            std::cout << cv::norm(contourDifferences2[cIdx]) << std::endl;
            cv::circle(colored, contourDifferences2Points[cIdx], 5, cv::Scalar(0,255,0));
            localOptima.push_back(contourDifferences2Points[cIdx]);
        }
    }


    // this should be 4 local optima in your setting if everything works fine.
    std::cout << "number of local Optima: " << localOptima.size() << std::endl;

    // these are the 4 bounding box corners.
    std::vector<cv::Point> cornersBB;
    cornersBB.push_back(cv::Point(bb.x, bb.y));
    cornersBB.push_back(cv::Point(bb.x+bb.width, bb.y));
    cornersBB.push_back(cv::Point(bb.x+bb.width, bb.y+bb.height));
    cornersBB.push_back(cv::Point(bb.x, bb.y+bb.height));

    std::vector<int> matchingBB2Contour(cornersBB.size(), -1);
    //std::vector<int> matchingContour2BB(localOptima.size(), -1);

    for(unsigned int i=0; i<cornersBB.size(); ++i)
    {
        float bestDist = FLT_MAX;
        for(unsigned int j=0; j<localOptima.size(); ++j)
        {
            float cDist = cv::norm(cornersBB[i] - localOptima[j]);
            if(cDist < bestDist)
            {
                bestDist = cDist;
                matchingBB2Contour[i] = j;
            }
        }
    }

    // todo: compute the best matching from contour optima to bounding box corners too and compare them.

    float contourOrientation = cv::contourArea(relevantContour, true); // negative = counter-clockwise
    std::cout << contourOrientation << std::endl;
    // now visualize the result:
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<cornersBB.size(); ++i)
    {
        cv::Scalar segmentColor(i*100, 255-(i*100), (i==3)?255:0);

        // color the bounding box segment too
        cv::line(colored, cornersBB[i], cornersBB[(i+1) % cornersBB.size()], segmentColor, 1);

        cv::Point startPoint = localOptima[matchingBB2Contour[i]];
        cv::Point endPoint = localOptima[matchingBB2Contour[(i+1)%matchingBB2Contour.size()] % localOptima.size()];
        int startIndex = -1;
        int endIndex = -1;
        for(unsigned int j=0; j<relevantContour.size(); ++j)
        {
            if(startPoint == relevantContour[j])
            {
                startIndex = j;
            }
            if(endPoint == relevantContour[j])
            {
                endIndex = j;
            }
        }

        // swap start and end if orientation is negative = contour is counter clockwise
        if(contourOrientation < 0)
        {
            int tmp = startIndex;
            startIndex = endIndex;
            endIndex = tmp;
        }

        std::cout << "start index: " << startIndex << std::endl;
        std::cout << "end index: " << endIndex << std::endl;

        //while(relevantContour[startIndex%relevantContour.size()] != endPoint)
        while(startIndex % relevantContour.size() != endIndex)
        {
            cv::circle(colored, relevantContour[startIndex%relevantContour.size()], 1, segmentColor);
            startIndex++;
        }

    }

    // show bb-to-contour correspondences:
    /*
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<matchingBB2Contour.size(); ++i)
    {
        cv::line(colored, localOptima[matchingBB2Contour[i]], cornersBB[i], cv::Scalar(0,0,255),2);
    }
    */


    cv::imshow("colored", colored);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the list of points of the contour returned by findContours.
Among these points, find the longest sequence with growing y (from S to E) and the longest sequence with decreasing y (opposite side). It might be that growing and decreasing are swapped, it depends if the contour returned by findContours is clockwise or counterclockwise, which is always a little bit problematic in image processing given the fact that the y-axis is swapped upside down.

Another way: find the baricenter of your contour points (or use the center of your bounding box), run along your contour points and see how the function "distance to the baricenter" changes: the 4 maxima points of this function are the corner of your trapezoidal figure. Caveat: in case your points are in integer coordinates, remember to use a distance expressed in floating point.

Of course, S and its mirrored corner are easy to find, because they have respectively minimum and maximum x. It could be a verification step (although incomplete) if you  implement one of the methods above.

Answer (score 0):

In OpenCV contour basically is just a list(well vector, but in this situation it doesn't matter) of points. Depending on settings used while extracting contours (findContours function) this list may contain all points which belongs to contour or just part of this list (which is approximation of whole list). If you use function [findContours](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours) and set mode to `CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE` you will get all contour points in the same order they appear in contour. Than you just need to find index of you S and E points (in this list) and get all elements between those 2 indexes.